# Repairing a 12V switch motor

Tags: motor, trains, repair, 12v

My son caused me to dig up my old 12V LEGO trains. Surprisingly they mostly work, except for [one part](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=70026&idColor=9#T=C&C=9) - Electric, Train 12V Remote Control Switch Motor 4 x 8 x 1 2/3:

[image]

This is the motor that drives the switches and railway crossings. I have 2 broken ones (and 2 working ones). One of them vibrates and buzzes a little but does not flip.  The other one is completely dead and the ohmmeter gives a broken connection.

Does anyone have anything that might me help fix them? Photos about how to open them, etc...

Comment: I doubt getting in there will be very easy, but I'd start on the vibrating one.  My 4.5V Technic motors  of similar vintage spin over but are very easily stalled.  I suspect the bearings need at least a good clean, possibly light grease but it depends on the details when you get inside

Answer (score 3):

Just repaired one...

https://youtu.be/XGyY8KtDnfA

Pry it open by using a precision knife on the lip of the bottom, using care to not damage the case:

[image: opening the case]

Inside you'll find a coil of copper wire. Check that the ends of the wire are properly soldered to the terminals, and re-solder if needed.

[image: Interior view showing copper wire coil]